# Why do my Ubuntu 12 and 14 Bittorrent seeds get so many downloads from Taiwan?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso-image, bittorrent, chinese

I will often open my Transmission control panel and see that old Ubuntu ISO files that I never removed from seeding are being downloaded. And it is usually from somewhere in Taiwan. These are the old Ubuntu 12 and 14 LTS distributions for the most part.

I would like to know why that is. Does Taiwan have a love for old Ubuntu distributions?

Comment: If you are from Taiwan and download old Ubuntu distributions you CAN answer this authoritatively. So not opinion based, close-voters.